# Plot factors side by side in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table as shown below, and I would like to make a scatterplot whereby the points for each factor is side by side instead. Is that possible?

```
fishers.drugs %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = Method, color=Method, x=Phenotype, y=OR, ymin = Lower.CI, ymax = Upper.CI)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(color=Method), show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_point(shape=21, size=12) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "cyan4"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","black"))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=34),axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Data:

```
fishers.drugs <- structure(list(Phenotype = c("SCZ", "BD", "MDD", "PTSD", "SCZ", 
"BD", "MDD", "PTSD"), P.value = c(3.6e-05, 7.6e-06, 0.0023, 0.03, 
0.29, 0.043, 0.19, 0.71), Method = c("Pairwise", "Pairwise", 
"Pairwise", "Pairwise", "MAGMA", "MAGMA", "MAGMA", "MAGMA"), 
    OR = c(3.1, 3.7, 2.53996, 2.6, 1.27, 1.9, 1.574722, 0.8), 
    Lower.CI = c(1.80232, 2.124302, 1.352569, 0.9064928, 0.5729662, 
    0.9067536, 0.7052697, 0.09566171), Upper.CI = c(4.846504, 
    6.090133, 4.40825, 5.8462159, 2.4825332, 3.6740963, 3.0758353, 
    3.01399383)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are picturing? I've changed positions for both points and error bars.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


fishers.drugs %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = Method, color=Method, x=Phenotype, y=OR, ymin = Lower.CI, ymax = Upper.CI)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(color=Method), show.legend = FALSE, position = position_dodge(width = 1))+
  geom_point(shape=21, size=12, position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "cyan4"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","black"))+
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=34),axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>